# Java EWS: Find folder with custom name

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to find mails inside of a custom folder.

This code snippet finds mails in well-known folders like `Inbox`, but what if I have a custom folder like `myFolder`? In this case it won't work, because `myFolder` is not a well-known folder name.

```
public void findAllMailsInFolderEWS(ExchangeService service, String mailbox, String folder){
    ItemView view = new ItemView(10);
    FindItemsResults<Item> findResults;

    WellKnownFolderName wkfn = WellKnownFolderName.valueOf(folder); // "Inbox" works, but I want "myFolder"
    FolderId folderId = new FolderId(wkfn, new Mailbox(mailbox));

    do {
        findResults = service.findItems(folderId, view);
        for (Item item : findResults.getItems()) {
            System.out.println(item.getSubject());
        }
        view.setOffset(view.getOffset() + pageSize);
    } while (findResults.isMoreAvailable());
}
```

How can I look for mails in folders with custom names?

Answer (score 0):

Use `FindFolder` EWS operation - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/findfolder-operation

Comment: Is there any Java example code?